# Question about about the continuity of the function $g(x) = x^n$ when $n$ is a whole number

Tags: limits, continuity

My textbook states that the function $g(x) = x^n$, where $n$ is a whole number, is continuous.

It proved it by stating the limit of $g(x) =$ limit of $x^n =$ limit of $c^n$.

However, I thought that if $n$ is $-1$, then the function would not be continuous.

Explain to me why $g(x) = x^n$ is always continuous when $n$ is a whole number.

Comment: Doesn't whole number mean a number $0, 1, 2, \ldots$?

Comment: Maybe; I googled the definition of a whole number and it defined it as equivalent to an integer.

Comment: $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is continuous on its domain $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: I've found that whole number means natural number, i.e. $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots\}$

Comment: Tomato, tahmahto.  Your text *probably* means non-negative and it *might* mean $0$.  If your text means negative values then $g(x)$ is continuous every where it is defined. Your text may or may not define that as continuous. Most advance texts would although elementary texts may assume all input is the real numbers at a real number not in the domain is discontinuous (but that really is not correct).

Comment: It seems odd it specified for whole numbers.  It's true for *all* real $n$.

Comment: If $f_1$ and $f_2$ are continuous then $f_1\cdot f_2$ is continuous. Therefore, by induction on $ n\in \Bbb Z^+,$ if $g_1,...,g_{n+1}$ are each continuous then $g_1\cdot ... \cdot g_{n+1}$ is continuous. That is, if $f_1=g_1\cdot ... \cdot g_n$ and $f_2=g_{n+1}$ are both continuous, then $f_1\cdot f_2$ is continuous. In particular, suppose $g_j(x)=x$ for every $j$ and every $x.$

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a function continuos usually refers to it being continuous in its domain. $f(x)=x^{-1}$ is continuous for $\Bbb R\backslash ${$0$}, which is its domain.The limits exist and are equal to $f(x)$. The function  doesn't even make sense for $x=0$. Of course, if you refer to it being continuous in $\Bbb R$, then it isn't.